# How to export dictionary as a .property file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, properties-file

How can a dictionary in python be exported to .properties file type in python?

What I have:

`dict = {"key1":"sentence1",  "key2":"sentence2"}`

The object `dict` should be saved as `.properties` file in python, the output should look like this:

```
key1=sentence1
key2=sentence2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use python built-in library `configparser`

```
import configparser

dict = {"key1":"sentence1",  "key2":"sentence2"}

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

# some your default section
section_name = "default"
config.add_section(section_name)

for (k, v) in dict.items():
    config.set(section_name, k, v)

with open("config.properties", "w") as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_dictionary={"key1":"sentence1",  "key2":"sentence2"}
with open("filename.properties", "w") as file:
    list_items=my_dictionary.items()
    for item in list_items:
        file.write(f"{item[0]}={item[1]}\n")
```

Comment: thanks. you might want to edit filename.property to filename.properties instead